# How do I convert NBA-API List to DataFrame

Tags: pandas, list, dataframe, nba-api

Having an issue converting NBA-API object to a DataFrame.  What I get is a list of the dataframe.  How do I pull the DataFrame out the list or skip the list and create the DataFrame.

```
## NBA API endpoints needed to obtain data
import nba_api.stats.endpoints
from nba_api.stats.static import players
from nba_api.stats.static import teams
from nba_api.stats.endpoints import shotchartdetail

import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

BBplayers = players.get_players()
BBteams = teams.get_teams()

print(type(players))
print(BBplayers[0])
print(len(BBplayers))
## LEN PLAYERS = 4501  PLAYER TYPE IS DICTIONARIES INSIDE LIST


Durant = [player for player in BBplayers if player['full_name'] == 'Kevin Durant'][0]
Durant_id = Durant['id']
print(Durant_id)
## Durant ID = 201142

Thunder = [name for name in BBteams if name['full_name']=='Oklahoma City Thunder'][0]
Thunder_id = Thunder['id']
print(Thunder_id)
print(type(Thunder_id))
## Thunder ID = 1610612760

DurantShotsChart = shotchartdetail.ShotChartDetail(player_id='201142',team_id=1610612760)

print(DurantShotsChart)

NewDF=DurantShotsChart.get_data_frames()

print(type(NewDF))
print(NewDF[1])
print(len(NewDF))
```

Comment: Didn't realize I could set a variable to the index of the list and pull out the dataframe.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [API documentation](https://github.com/swar/nba_api/blob/master/docs/nba_api/stats/endpoints/shotchartdetail.md) you should get two dataframes. And since the `get_data_frames` method always outputs a list of DataFrames, you can retrieve them separately by indexing:

```
league_averages = NewDF[0]
```

Which has the columns `['GRID_TYPE', 'SHOT_ZONE_BASIC', 'SHOT_ZONE_AREA', 'SHOT_ZONE_RANGE', 'FGA', 'FGM', 'FG_PCT']`.

And then

```
shot_chart_detail= NewDf[1]
```

Which has the following columns `['GRID_TYPE', 'GAME_ID', 'GAME_EVENT_ID', 'PLAYER_ID', 'PLAYER_NAME', 'TEAM_ID', 'TEAM_NAME', 'PERIOD', 'MINUTES_REMAINING', 'SECONDS_REMAINING', 'EVENT_TYPE', 'ACTION_TYPE', 'SHOT_TYPE', 'SHOT_ZONE_BASIC', 'SHOT_ZONE_AREA', 'SHOT_ZONE_RANGE', 'SHOT_DISTANCE', 'LOC_X', 'LOC_Y', 'SHOT_ATTEMPTED_FLAG', 'SHOT_MADE_FLAG', 'GAME_DATE', 'HTM', 'VTM']`

Answer (score 1):

This?

```
df1=NewDF[0]
df2=NewDF[1]
```